# Create a DELETE statement that deletes Manufacturers with less than 10 sales

Tags: database-design, subquery, sqlite

**Orders:**

```
Order number (Primary Key)
Date of order
Customer ID (Primary Key for Customers table)
Serial Number (Primary Key for Machines table)
```

**Customers:**

```
ID (Primary Key)
Name
Phone Number
Street (ie. 505 Ramapo Valley Road)
City (ie. Mahwah)
State
Zip
```

**Machines:**

```
Serial Number (Primary Key)
Model Number (Primary Key for Models table)
```

**Model:**

```
ID (Primary key)
Speed
RAM
HD
Price
Manufacturer ID (Primary key for Manufacturer table)
```

**Manufacturer:**

```
ID (Primary Key)
Name
Phone Number
Email Address
```

Above are tables with different attributes.

I have a lab due soon and one of the tasks is to create an SQLite statement to DELETE Manufacturers with less than ten sales. I have tried to write a sub query, but am not able to formulate a statement that works. The following is what I have so far:
(I know I am off by a lot)

```
DELETE FROM Manufacturer    
HAVING COUNT(*) < 10
WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ManufacturerID FROM Model WHERE Manufacturer
    WHERE Manufacturer.ID = Model.ManufacturerID

SELECT ModelNo FROM Machines
    WHERE Machines.ModelNo = Model.ID

SELECT SerialNo FROM Orders
    ON Orders.SerialNo = Machines.SerialNo
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.StackExchange.com! I cleaned up your question's formatting a little bit, but could you please review the query in the last code block and verify it says what you want it to say?...it's currently an incomplete query that is syntactically invalid.

Comment: First write a query to find the Manufacturers with fewer than 10 sales.  Get that working, and then put it in a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're not too far off, you're just missing a couple key things, the first being the `JOIN` keyword. `JOIN` is how you can combine two related datasets. There are different types of joins, one being an [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/) which is how you can combine two datasets and only return the rows that match the join condition. For example, if you wanted to get only `Customers` who have an `Order` and you want to know the `Name` of that `Customer` and the `SerialNumber` of their `Order` you could do so with an `INNER JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT Customers.Name, Orders.SerialNumber
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Customers.ID = Orders.CustomerID
```

You can join as many datasets as you like in a single query. So if we also wanted to know the `ModelNumber` for the above Customers' Orders, we could modify the above query like so:

```
SELECT Customers.Name, Orders.SerialNumber, Machines.ModelNumber
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Customers.ID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Machines
    ON Orders.SerialNumber = Machines.SerialNumber
```

---

Deriving from the above example we can do the same to get a list of all Manufacturers' Orders, by chaining together a bunch of `INNER JOIN` clauses. Lets only return the `ID` of the `Manufacturer` as well, since that's all we care about right now. Note since this is a list of all Manufacturers' Orders, there will be one row for every `Order`, so you should see the same `ID` of the `Manufacturer` repeated in cases where they have more than one order:

```
SELECT Manufacturer.ID
FROM Manufacturer
INNER JOIN Model
    ON Manufacturer.ID = Model.ManufacturerID
INNER JOIN Machines
    ON Model.ID = Machines.ModelNumber
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Machines.SerialNumber = Orders.SerialNumber
```

Now you need a way to count how many `Orders` (how many rows) there are for each `Manufacturer.ID` from the previous query. To do that we can use the built in [`COUNT()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-count-function/) function. Because we want to count the number of `Orders` for a certain criteria (by `Manufacturer`), we'll also need to use the [`GROUP BY`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/) clause. The `GROUP BY` clause allows us to roll-up (flatten) all the rows by the criteria we specify into a single unique row per grouping based on the columns we specify. In this case we just want a single row per `Manufacturer.ID` so that when we use the `COUNT()` function, it counts the number of `Orders` within that grouping, like so:

```
SELECT Manufacturer.ID, COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
FROM Manufacturer
INNER JOIN Model
    ON Manufacturer.ID = Model.ManufacturerID
INNER JOIN Machines
    ON Model.ID = Machines.ModelNumber
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Machines.SerialNumber = Orders.SerialNumber
GROUP BY Manufacturer.ID
```

So the above query now gives us the list of Manufacturer IDs and the count of how many `Orders` each one has. Let's filter it down to only the Manufacturers who have less than 10 `Orders`. We will use the [`HAVING`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-having/) clause to accomplish this, which is the equivalent of using a `WHERE` clause to filter data but can only be used with aggregate functions like `COUNT()` on grouped data:

```
SELECT Manufacturer.ID, COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
FROM Manufacturer
INNER JOIN Model
    ON Manufacturer.ID = Model.ManufacturerID
INNER JOIN Machines
    ON Model.ID = Machines.ModelNumber
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Machines.SerialNumber = Orders.SerialNumber
GROUP BY Manufacturer.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) < 10 -- Filter out everything except Manufacturers with less than 10 Orders
```

Finally, we want to use a subquery as you mentioned, so we can `DELETE` the results in our above query from the `Manufacturer` table like so:

```
DELETE FROM Manufacturer
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT Manufacturer.ID
    FROM Manufacturer
    INNER JOIN Model
        ON Manufacturer.ID = Model.ManufacturerID
    INNER JOIN Machines
        ON Model.ID = Machines.ModelNumber
    INNER JOIN Orders
        ON Machines.SerialNumber = Orders.SerialNumber
    GROUP BY Manufacturer.ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 10 -- Filter out everything except Manufacturers with less than 10 Orders
)
```

Note that when you use a subquery inside of the `IN` keyword, you can only return one column, and for your case you only care about the `ID` of the `Manufacturers` for who needs to be deleted. So I removed the `OrderCount` column from the subquery above.

There are definitely alternative ways to accomplish the above as well, but to keep the concepts you need to understand to a minimal, this is a pretty good solution. The concepts I hope you took away from this are:

1. [**Joins**](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-join/), specifically the [`INNER JOIN` clause](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/), and you should research [**Outer Joins**](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-left-join/) as well.
2. [**Aggregate Functions**](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-aggregate-functions/) such as [`COUNT()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-count-function/), there are many others too such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, and `SUM()`, etc.
3. The [`GROUP BY` clause](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/) and how [grouping](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_group_by.htm) works in general.
4. The [`HAVING` clause](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-having/) and how and when to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! You responded with an in depth answer and thoroughly explained each concept. I appreciate it!

Comment: @DonaldAlesson Great, no problem, glad I could help! Certainly not required, but feel free to accept and/or upvote my answer so other users with similar questions see it verified as helpful. If you have any other questions, feel free and I'll do my best to answer them.

Comment: I would like to ask you why you wrote WHERE ID IN (). I understand we need to use the IN keyword to return one column, but what was the reason for using the word ID? Was it because that is how we are linking the Manufacturers with the amount of orders they have? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @DonaldAlesson The `ID` is the key column in the `Manufacturer` table, so I'm specifying it in the `WHERE` clause before the `IN` keyword to create a logical expression for the `DELETE` statement, that basically says the ID of the Manufacturer has to be in the list of IDs returned from the subquery inside the `IN` clause.